# how to remove duplicate data in mysql based on code and filter based on user and curr

Tags: mysql, sql, filter, distinct, string-length

| Date | time | seq | debet | credit | curr | nominal | trx | user | checker | ket |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/1/2022 | 8:01:01 AM | 1 | 11-47007-7101-1722704-0000-00000 | 800135681140 | USD | 222 | CGD | SX40107X | RS04536X | SUCCESFUL |
| 12/1/2022 | 8:01:01 AM | 2 | 800135681140 | 11-47007-7101-2722855-0502-00000 | IDR | 123000000 | CDG | SX40107X | RS04536X | SUCCESFUL |
| 12/1/2022 | 8:01:01 AM | 3 | 11-47007-7101-2722855-0502-00000 | 4700722341640190000 | IDR | 123030000 | CRG | SX40107X | RS04536X | SUCCESFUL |
| 12/1/2022 | 8:01:01 AM | 3 | 11-00014-7510-5903199-0000-00000 | 11-47007-7101-2722855-0502-00000 | IDR | 30000 | GTG | SX40107X | RS04536X | SUCCESFUL |

how to get rid of the same debit and credit codes based on the longest debit code to display the credit debit nominal filtered based on curr and user to be like this

user : SX40107X

| date | sl/account | debet | credit | ket |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/1/2022 | 11-47007-7101-2722855-0502-00000 | 123030000 | 123030000 | SUCCESFUL |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the column `debet` and `credit` it becomes easy to aggregate. The rest is just formatting. For example:

```
select
  max(date) as date,
  case when length(l) > length(g) then l else g end as sl_acc,
  sum(debet) as debet,
  sum(credit) as credit,
  ket
from (
  select t.*, least(debet, credit) as l, greatest(debet, credit) as g from t
) x
group by l, g, ket
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but how to bring up the nominal based on the sl number

Comment: @DistrictArtem Hi, I don't understand your comment. Please elaborate.